# Scikit-Learn Pipeline: How to Handle Preprocessing

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm doing some machine learning practice on Kaggle and I'm beginning to use the `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` class to transform my data several times and then train a model on it.

I want to encapsulate several parts of pre-processing my data: dropping rows with 30% or more `NaN`s, dropping columns with 30% or more `NaN`s, amongst other things.

Here's the start of my attempt at a custom `Transformer`:

```
class NanHandler(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, target_col, row_threshold=0.7, col_threshold=0.7):
        self.target_col = target_col
        self.row_threshold = row_threshold
        self.col_threshold = col_threshold
    def transform(self, X):
        # drop rows and columns with >= 30% NaN values
    def fit(self, *_):
        return self
```

However, I want to use this `Transformer` with k-fold cross-validation.  I'm concerned that if I do 3-fold cross-validation, it's unlikely (but possible) that I run into the following situation:

Train on folds 1 and 2, test on 3

Train on folds 2 and 3, test on 1

Train on folds 1 and 3, test on 2

Folds 1 and 2 combined may have over 30% `Nan`s in a specific column (call it `colA`).  So my `NanHandler` will drop this column before training.  However, folds 2 and 3 combined may have less than 30% `NaN`s and so it *won't* drop `colA`, resulting my model being trained on different columns than the first pass.

1) How should I handle this situation?

2) Is this also a problem if I want to drop rows that have 30% ore more NaN values (in that I'll train on a different number of rows during k-fold cross-validation)?

Thanks!

Comment: Missing values should be handled for the whole dataset and not separately for train and test.

Comment: @Vivek Kumar that's wrong. The preprocessing has to be done separately for the train set and test set, otherwise the test set won't be "clean". In this case maybe stratified cross-validation will work or dropping the features altogether.

Answer (score 2):

The figure 30% is a little ambiguous to me. 30% of your entire dataset or 30% in each fold? For example, if you have a dataset with 90 samples and you break it up to 3 folds of 30. would you want 70% of cols and rows in a fold of 30 points to be present? (I'm going to assume that this is the case)

Then perhaps the following could work:

1. Clear your entire dataset of all features and samples that have any missing values(`Nan`) and create a pool of data points that have at least one `Nan`.
2. Then build your folds.
3. Now, based on your number of
   features and examples you can resample points from your pool of
   points with `Nan` and add it back to each of your folds.

I hope this helps.